# How to put a specific message in the "response body" of a perl Dancer server

Tags: perl, response, dancer

My RESTfull server with Perl Dancer runs perfectly with one exception: `send_error("Simple Error string",400)` for example removes the error message.

The error code will be sent, but without the actual message "Simple Error string".

I tried `return send_entity({ error => "Missing parameter "}, 400)` with no avail too.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
##########################################################################################################################################
# V1.0 REST-Server
##########################################################################################################################################


use Dancer;
use Dancer::Plugin::Auth::Basic;
use Dancer::Plugin::Database;
use Dancer::Plugin::REST;

set serializer => 'XML';

post '/hello/:name' => sub 
{
  # Low level test route
  auth_basic realm => 'Authorized personnel only', users => { 'alice' => 'AlicesPassword', 'bob' => 'BobsPassword' };
  send_error("Simple Error string",400);
};
dance;
```

The tests take place with curl:

```
#curl -X POST -k -u alice:AlicesPassword http://localhost:5000/hello/abc
An internal error occured
```

and with RESTer under Firefox (via https proxy).

RESTer reports the same.

Several googling brought no hints, how to produce the correct error code AND the provided message.

I hope anybody can give me a hint.

Comment: Why are you using Rest::Client and XML::Simple and MIME::Base64? Are those leftovers from pruning your code to a [mcve]? Which version of Dancer is this?

Comment: Sorry you are right, that are indeed leftovers from the bigger code!

Comment: Right! I removed the --data extension. It is not necessary to show the error. Thank you for your tips to show a verifiyable example, it's my first post!

Comment: I can't get it to work either, and I don't see where that error message comes from. I added a `get` which works, and if you just `return "foo"` from the `post` sub it also works, even without anything but `use Dancer;`. But as soon as the `send_error` is there, it breaks. That's weird. But note that `send_error("foo", 500)` will produce an HTTP Response with the status `500 foo`. That `foo` does not go into the body the way you expect it to.

Comment: send_error breaks the route. That's documenented. Yes, a single 'return "foo"' works, but with the http status code 200. I look for a way to send a code with 4XX or 5XX together with a message. I am experimenting with `return send_entity({ error => $message}, 500)`. This seems to work better. I'll post here, if I know more.

Comment: Well you can do https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#status and `return "something went horribly wrong";`

Comment: For `return "something went horribly wrong"` the http status code is 200. Doesn't help!

Comment: Even if you set a status explicitly?

Comment: How would you set a status explicitly?

Comment: I just said above.

Comment: Oh yes, you meant `status 400; return "error message"`! Indeed that's it what I looked for!! Don't ask me why I discovered the `status` keyword not ealier! How can I mark this thread as solved? Thank you very much!

Comment: I will post an answer.

Comment: You can accept my answer by clicking the check mark. See [ask]. I typed all this from my phone. Not fun. :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simply change the Http status you can use the [`status` keyword](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#status) and return your content as the response body.

```
get '/' => sub {
  status 418;
  return 'I cannot make coffee.';
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but your example only makes sense if the webserver is running on a teapot ;P

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Thank you for fixing the markup. That was my phone. And it's obvious it's a teapot, isn't it? :)

Comment: You helped me really much, some times the solution  is so obvious!

Comment: @cablebuddy This was actually a very good first question. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Thanks for the "flowers", I'm sure to be here not the last time! I was really surprised how big StackExchange is and that not only computer and programming questions are handled here. Fantastic!

Comment: @cablebuddy it can get quite time-consuming. Don't read the hot network questions if you have `$work` to do. ;)